# TCP Socket send/receive always waiting

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I have a `TCP` connection between a server and a client. Server sending data, client receiving data and client feedback the server. But if client closes socket and creates again, server never accept it because it is waiting feedback from client. So how can i solve that?

**Server**

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];
string ip = "192.168.1.17";
int port = 15500;

IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(ip);
IPEndPoint localEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);

Socket sock = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

Console.WriteLine("Waiting client...");
sock.Bind(localEndpoint);
sock.Listen(5);

Socket confd = sock.Accept();

Console.WriteLine("Connected with {0} at port {1}", ip, port);
Sender sender = new Sender();
Receiver receiver = new Receiver();

while (true) {
    if (confd.Connected) {
        sender.SendData(confd);
        receiver.ReceiveData(confd); //Waiting here
    } 
    else {
        confd.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting client...");
        confd = sock.Accept();
    }
}
```

Comment: before closing the connection, send a "hey server! i want to close the connection!" or something like that. so the server can handle it an close it's connection too and doesn't need to listen for a feedback

Comment: @TE: create a list<Action> where you can add a delegate to a function that is handling the current connection

Comment: @Radinator I accepted  _MarcGravell_'s answer but i want to try this too. For the first comment what if connection forced to close by android, like shutdown application or disconnect wifi?

Comment: @Pareidolia then it *might* close down the server socket cleanly; it *might* close after a few seconds, or it *might* never be detected as closed. Sockets are fun like that. Thus: a handshake shutdown is **nice** (and should be encouraged), but it shouldn't be *relied upon*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a thread per socket is usually a bad idea. Having a **single** thread that deals with socket IO and accepting connections is usually a terrible idea. There are a myriad reasons why a socket disconnect can go unnoticed - either for a while, or in some cases: indefinitely. The way to avoid this problem is usually to have one thread (or theses days: `async` loop) dedicated to accepting connections, and initializing connections, and then rather than creating a thread per socket, use async IO to read/write without requiring threads. Although if you have a very low number of sockets, you *might* be able to get away with thread-per-socket. Finally, either use read/write timeouts, or have a periodic "have I seen this socket lately?" check (over all sockets), to help shut down sockets that have failed silently.

Comment: @TE: create a list<Action> where you can add a delegate to a function that is handling the current connection

Comment: @Radinator was this the post you meant to comment on?

Comment: @Radinator but.... who is TE? and what is that comment responding to? confused...

Comment: Looks like copy paste =)

Comment: @MarcGravell: sry...TE is german ("Thread Ersteller") for thread creator